# vector calculus formulas proof

Tags: vectors, laplacian

I would like to ask how to prove these two formulas.

for T is a scalar and **r** is radial component of a vector in spherical coordinate.

(1)

$$
{\bf{r}\cdot[(r\cdot\nabla)\nabla}T+2\nabla T]={\bf{r}\cdot\nabla} T+{\bf r\cdot\nabla(r\cdot\nabla} T)
$$

(2)
$$
{\nabla^2(T\bf{r})}={\bf {r}}\nabla^2T+T\nabla^2{\bf {r}}+2\nabla T\cdot\nabla {\bf {r}}
$$

Thank you !!

Comment: $\mathbf{r}$ is not just any vector.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, I edited and it should be a radial component of a vector in spherical coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), note that
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{r}\cdot[(\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla)\nabla T+2\nabla T]
&=x_i[(x_j\partial_j)\partial_i T+2\partial_i T]\\
&=x_i(x_j\partial_j)\partial_i T+2x_i\partial_i T\\
&=x_j\partial_jx_i\partial_i T-x_j(\partial_j x_i)\partial_i T+2x_i\partial_i T\\
&=x_j\partial_jx_i\partial_i T-x_j\delta_{ij}\partial_i T+2x_i\partial_i T\\
&=x_j\partial_jx_i\partial_i T-x_i\partial_i T+2x_i\partial_i T\\
&=x_j\partial_jx_i\partial_i T+x_i\partial_i T\\
&=\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla(\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla T)+\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla T
\end{align*}

(2) is similar.

Comment: Wow, really thanks a lot!!
one more question is how
$$
x_i(x_j\partial_j)\partial_i T=x_j\partial_jx_i\partial_i T
$$
change its partial position?

Comment: They are not equal.  Applying the usual product rule for derivatives: $\partial_j x_i f = (\partial_j x_i)f+x_i\partial_j f$

Comment: Sorry for the stupid typing error, but I finally understand!! Thank you very much again!